# cmake, can I build a library from an executable objects

Tags: c++, cmake, static-linking

I have a c++ project build with cmake.

```
add_executable(app foo.cpp bar.cpp main.cpp)
```

And I would like to use `foo.cpp` and `bar.cpp` in a test project.

I know I could build a library and then link it in both projects:
like:

```
add_library(foobar foo.cpp bar.cpp)

add_executable(app main.cpp)
target_link_library(app foobar)

add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_link_library(test foobar)
```

But I would rather not change the app build system and link `test` against the objects `foo.o` and `bar.o`.

Do you know how I could do that with cmake?

Comment: Is the title meant to say "cmake"?

Comment: You could just build the .cpp files for "test" another time. More clean to me than trying to reuse object files.

Comment: I think you can link object files as libraries `target_link_library(test foo.o bar.o)`

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, yes this might end up cleaner but I would like to investigate other solutions.

Comment: @gomons, sounds like a good solution but the problem is that the path to the object files is platform dependent, do you know the cmake variables and commands to reference them robustly? I will search as well.

Comment: @olivelarouille, If you build app and test from one sources, you can use variable CMAKE_BINARY_DIR and use relative path to you object files: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR }/Project/ObjectFiles/foo.o

Comment: Take a look at [object libraries](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library).

Comment: Preamble: you cannot link to an executable, so you have to change something in the way you build things. Some solutions proposed here are risky. Just make your foobar library a static library `add_library(foobar STATIC foo.cpp bar.cpp)` and keep the code you proposed in the beginning. Don't go for linking directly to object files, you'll end up with so much pain in trying to find where your object files end up when you change anything, cmake is meant to simplify this kind of things, use the right architecture for your project! And take a look to sakra proposal, which is good.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, @Antonio, I would accept you answer because it seems the most appropriate in most use cases, linking to the object files seems unpractical since we have to enumerate them individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preamble: you cannot link to an executable, so you have to change something in the way you build things.

Some solutions proposed in the comments are risky. Don't go for linking directly to object files, you'll end up with so much pain in trying to find where your object files end up when you change anything, cmake is meant to simplify this kind of things, the general suggestion is to use the right architecture for your project.

Proposed solutions:

- Just make your foobar library a static library `add_library(foobar STATIC foo.cpp bar.cpp)` and keep the code you proposed in the beginning.
- Or, take a look to sakra proposal ([object libraries](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library)), which is good.